# SigmaJs Adding More Node Attributes

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I am trying to add info on nodes. JSON imported to graph by this way:

```
$.getJSON...
     s = new sigma({
        graph: json,
        settings: {
            enableHovering: false
      }
```

JSON file have more attributes than sigma searched for import graph. For example

```
"nodes": [{"size": 3.104487111312395, "color": "rgb(181, 229, 127)", 
    "attributes": {"pp": "...jpg"}, "id":1,"x":1,"y":1,
```

But sigmajs did not import these atributes to graph and it uses only x y color and size.

```
    <circle data-node-id="1" class="sigma-node" fill="rgb(85, 184, 141)"
 cx="357.70791360671683" cy="-151.86561654993392" r="1.8292755337720816"
 style="display: none;"></circle>
```

How can i import additional attributes to sigma nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the SVG renderer, Sigma just take those attributs :

- color
- id
- x
- y
- size

Take a look here : https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.nodes.def.js#L43-L45

After if you want to have more data on your SVG object, you have :

- override sigma.svg.nodes.def.js file with your own
- enhanced your SVG after its generation with a little JS script  :  make a loop on sigma's nodes array, take the SVG element by its id, and do what you want

But for my curiosity, why do you want to do this ?

Cheers